# Can't load custom onnx model in react native

Tags: react-native, onnx

I'm trying to create an app that converts a pre-trained yolov8 model on react native to onnx format and then performs object detection. but can't load it. like this,
May I ask where is wrong?

1. create project

> expo init ExampleProject -> typescript blank project

2. paste onnx model to ./assets/model/

   ```
                import {InferenceSession ,Tensor} from 'onnxruntime-react-native';
            export default function App() {




              const [onnxSession, setOnnxSession] = useState<InferenceSession | null>(null);




              useEffect(() => {
                if (hasPermission && onnxSession === null) {
                  startOnnxRuntimeSession();
                }
              }, [hasPermission, onnxSession]);



              const startOnnxRuntimeSession  = async () => {
                try {
                  // Path to the ONNX model asset
                  const modelAsset = require('./assets/model/best.onnx');
                  const asset = Asset.fromModule(modelAsset);
                  if (!asset.localUri) {
                    await asset.downloadAsync();
                  }

                  const session = await InferenceSession.create(asset.localUri);
                  setOnnxSession(session);
                  console.log('ONNX session started successfully');

                  const modelInfo = await session.getInfo();
                  console.log(modelInfo);
                }
                catch(error){
                  console.log('Error while starting the ONNX sessiong:',error);
                }
              };
            }
   ```

and I've got a following error message.

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
> Error: Can't load a model: Cannot read property 'loadModel' of null